# Missing files when copying from src to dist?

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, gulp-imagemin

```
var srcArticleImage = 'src/recommended-reads-images/';
var distArticleImage = 'dist/assets/recommended-reads-images/';

gulp.task('article-images', function() {
gulp.src(srcArticleImage + "*", srcArticleImage + "**/*"])
    .pipe(gulpif(global.build, imagemin([
        imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
        imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
        imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 5}),
        imagemin.svgo({plugins: [{removeViewBox: true}]})
    ])))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(distArticleImage))
    .pipe(gulpif(global.build, size({showFiles: true, showTotal: false})))
    .pipe(gulpif(!global.build, notify({message: 'Article Images Compiled', onLast: true})))
});
```

When the above task is run, I expect it to take the files from the src directory, minify them and then copy them over to the destination.

However I have a problem when the task runs. Only 81 images are being output to the destination folder, but there are 103 files in the src folder.

Would appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on this issue, I have bashed my head against the keyboard for an hour and a half trying to fix this issue.

Hope somebody has the fix, thanks.

Comment: I would say that the 22 files that are missing doesn´t match the criteria from `gulp.src`. I would suggest to find out the pattern that these files have (maybe all of them are at the same folder, or have the same extension, I don´t know). But if you prefer, first you can remove all the processing stuff (minification, etc.) and try just to move from the source to the destination (`gulp.src` and `gulp.dest`) and verify if all files are being moved, if not you have a problem at gulp.src, if all files have been moved you should look at the other pipes. Regards.

Comment: And I forgot to mention, I don´t if this is the same code you are running but if it is, your code is missing the array open brackets `gulp.src(srcArticleImage + "*", srcArticleImage + "**/*"])`. Regards.

Comment: Whoops thanks for spotting in this example. This checked and the missing bracket is there in my file. Still not too sure how to process all of the images, something funny is happening and it's beyond me. Ive tried stripping it back just to get the files to copy over but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Whay do you mean when you say "haven´t had any luck"? They files still missed? Didn´t copy any files at all? I believe that would help posting the folder structure where these files are so other people can try to spot where the error is. Have you noted any pattern on the missing files?

Comment: Try simplifying your src glob.  I don't believe the first glob adds anything that is not captured by the second glob: gulp.src( srcArticleImage + "**/*")  since the globstar ** matches 0 or more directories it will catch those the first removed glob catches.  I don't know if this is your problem but you might as well try it.